# When is better to @Inject a CDI than to instantiate a

Tags: java, performance, jakarta-ee, cdi

What are those situations in which is better to inject an instance of a generic object through CDI than to instantiate through `SomeObject newObject = new SomeObject()` ?
With look at performance, architecture, modularity, instance reusability, caching, transactions, etc etc...

Thank you!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13047807/why-use-cdi-in-java-ee

Comment: Short answer: Whenever you can.